# Is there a relationship between Kafka Connect and Kafka Streams commit interval?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

Let's say we have a Kafka Sink Connector populating a database from a topic `TopicA`,

And a Kafka Stream App pushing updates to that `TopicA` topic.

I would like to know if:

- The data updated into the database by the Sink connector, and
- The moment when those updates are performed

are influenced by the Kafka Streams App commit interval, and if yes, How ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Kafka Stream App ( is a Kafka producer **and consumer** )
- Kafka Sink Connector ( is only a Kafka consumer )

Kafka producer have absolutely no influence on the commit interval of Kafka consumers. You just have to take care that Kafka producers are not faster that your consumers to avoid consumer group lag. With a slow consumer there are chances of data loss.

Comment: Could you please explain this statement "You just have to take care that Kafka producers are not faster that your consumers to avoid consumer group lag. With a slow consumer there are chances of data loss." ?

Comment: Speed of the message produced should be always less than the speed of consumed  messages @IskuskovAlexander

Comment: In general, this is not entirely correct. We can look at Kafka in this context is that it acts as a giant buffer that decouples the time-sensitivity requirements between producers and consumers. Producers can write events in real-time while consumers process batches of events, or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

I would say they are, indeed, related.

If the Streams producer threads commit more frequently, then the data arrives on the topic faster, and therefore the Connect Sink will pull the data more rapidly, ultimately invoking more queries against the database. Vice-versa for less throughput.

However, each component is individually tunable.

Comment: I asked that question because I have bizarre results: I have a tasks topic with a schema containing `(task_id, status, error_message)`. When created, a task looks like this `(task_id="xxx", status="processing", error_message="")`. If a task fails, an update like this is published `(task_id="xxx", status="done", error_message="bad error")`. Note that the topic is compacted. When I consume it with a `KTable`, everything is right. But in my database (Cassandra), sometimes it is good, sometimes I have this `(task_id="xxx", status="processing", error_message="bad error")`.

Comment: Note how the error message as been updated, but the status is still processing. I have no idea where to start troubleshooting this.

Comment: I even suspected my total memory, so I upgraded from 8GB to 16GB, but I still have random results. You can see how lost I am.

Comment: I assume you are using the Datastax connect sink? Even so, I don't see how that is related to the streams job from doing anything specific. You should enable DEBUG logging on the streams job

Comment: Indeed I am using Datastax connect sink. OK I will check the debug logs. Thanks

Comment: Note that I got the same effects with the Confluent's Cassandra sink, that is why I tried the one from Datastax.

Comment: I've never used the Confluent one. I trust Datastax more since they are the company supporting Cassandra and maintain the drivers